# Error installing devise for rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to migrate an existing app to ruby 2.0 + rails 4.0 and so far everything is working except that when I try to install devise:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

I get the following error:

```
Exiting
    /home/lemur/rails_projects/delicateca/config/initializers/devise.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `skip_session_storage=' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise.rb:252:in `setup'
        from /home/lemur/rails_projects/delicateca/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/engine.rb:607:in `each'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/engine.rb:607:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:186:in `each'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:186:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:154:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `initialize!'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/lemur/rails_projects/delicateca/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/lemur/rails_projects/delicateca/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/lemur/rails_projects/delicateca/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/lemur/rails_projects/delicateca/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:71:in `start'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from /home/lemur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

I get the same error when I try to run the app just doing bundle install and then rails s.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a dependency issue, as explained by Aaron Paterson:

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/12/18/rails-4-and-your-gemfile.html

The solution (in the comments) is updating your gemfile with:

gem 'devise', github: 'idl3/devise', branch: 'rails4'

Answer (score 5):

[UPDATE]

The rails4 branch has now been merged into master. So this should be all you need now:

`gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'`

I've left my old answer below.

================================================

The easiest fix today is to use the following in your gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'
```

More details can be found on the [comment](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2172#issuecomment-13902420) of this pull request for Devise.

At the time of [Lemurido's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476374/lemurido) response, his was the best solution to your error.